# Chrome does not respect display property on table elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Is there any particular reason why chrome does not respect `"display:inline"` when it's used on `"<table>"` and is there a known workaround? Everything works fine in firefox but for some reason chrome refuses to do the right thing when I type

```
<table style="display:inline;">
    table stuff
</table>
```

firefox alignment: [firefox alignment http://dkarapet.userworld.com/cart_noDB/firefox_alignment.png](http://dkarapet.userworld.com/cart_noDB/firefox_alignment.png)

chrome alignment: [chrome alignment http://dkarapet.userworld.com/cart_noDB/chrome_alignment.png](http://dkarapet.userworld.com/cart_noDB/chrome_alignment.png)

Both versions use the same html source that sets the display property to inline. The tables individually are not wrapped inside any other div and they are all enclosed inside one big div. Here's the [pastie](http://pastie.org/1042134) for the relevant part of the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull of what you're after, you just need to add this to every td:

```
<td valign="top">
```

That will force everything to the top of each cell and will force things to display inline, how you want them to. No CSS needed here.

It SHOULD be coded like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top">item 1 info</td>
  <td valign="top">item 2 info</td>
  <td valign="top">item 3 info</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top">item 4 info</td>
  <td valign="top">item 5 info</td>
  <td valign="top">item 6 info</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

edit: Or if (for some reason) you're not using TR and TD's you can try this:

```
<table style="vertical-align:top;">
    table stuff
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks dude. That did the trick. Now it displays the same way in chrome and firefox. I'm not even gonna bother with IE.

Comment: i had that in my comments 16 mins ago :p

Comment: @meder - you just listed some vague comment about `vertical-align` which applies to at least three different elements in the table. @Tim actually listed the exact code that did the trick that's why I accepted his answer.

Comment: ok sorry, i assumed you knew what common elements to apply it to, and assumed you could test it out fairly quick. i hope you arent actually using the attribute though.

Comment: @meder - No need to apologize.

Answer (score 7):

Try `inline-block`.

Comment: Surely this is the correct answer? Works like a dream, and is more semantic than 'vertical-align:top'?

Answer (score 3):

css 2.1 defines `inline-table`. No idea how widely supported it is, but it sounds like that might be what you're looking for.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display

Although from your screenshot, it looks like what you really want is control over vertical alignment.

Comment: Browser support information, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 2):

Why on earth would you set a table element to be inline? It should be a display of table. User error IMO.

You'd have to alter the display mode of all the `tr` and `td` elements inside otherwise they will improperly render, most likely.

If you need the table to be in the same line as another element, wrap a div around the table and float it. Don't mess with the table.

**EDIT:** As I specified per my last comment, you should mess with `vertical-align` and probably set it to top on the tables.

Comment: What do you mean why? Because sometimes you want tables to stack next to each other instead of piling up one on top of the other. How is that a user error?

Comment: @meder - I did and maybe I'm missing something but the alignment is still off. All the tables are aligned with the last row, so if one of the tables is too tall then it sticks out. I want them to align with the top row so even if the tables are uneven their tops are aligned.

Comment: @meder - firefox has no problem with this and cheerfully does as I tell it to and aligns all the tables with their top rows.

Comment: @meder - floating and clearing doesn't help either since I don't know ahead of time which tables are going to be larger than the others on a given line and some elements in one line inadvertently block the elements below them and don't let them float all the way to the left.

Comment: @meder - floating and clearing would work if I knew exactly which elements to clear and I can do some processing with javascript to do so but that's too much work for having consistent layout across chrome and firefox.

Comment: It might be useful if you actually posted a demo so we can see your floating problem. Comment bombardment.

Comment: do your screenshots represent display:inline method or float? if display:inline you'll probably have to tinker w/ vertical-align and set it to top. link to source pls.